# How to submit a form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to submit a form using jQuery, so I have 4 fields that needed to be checked, but when I submit, it displays the first alert `submit` but i doesn't check if the fields are valid or not. What's the error in my code? Much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=subdomain]').keyup(subdomain_check);
$('input[name=password]').keyup(password_strenght);
$('input[name=c_password]').keyup(password_check);
$('input[name=email]').keyup(email_check);

$('#install').on('submit', function(){
alert("submit");
if ($('input[name=subdomain]').valid() == true && $('input[name=password]').valid() == true && $('input[name=c_password]').valid() == true &&   $('input[name=email]').valid() == true){
    alert("TRUE");
    return true;
} else {
    alert("FALSE");
    return false;
    }
});

});
```

Here's The HTML form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="install" action="etape2.html" role="form">
        <input type="hidden" id="install-element-0" value="install" name="form">
        <input type="hidden" id="install-element-1" value="insert" name="action">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" id="install-element-2" required="" name="title" class="form-control input-md col-md-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" id="install-element-3" required="" name="first_name" class="form-control input-md col-md-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" id="install-element-4" required="" name="last_name" class="form-control input-md col-md-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" id="install-element-5" required="" name="email" class="form-control input-md col-md-6">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="password" id="install-element-6" required="" class="form-control input-md col-md-6" name="password">
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" id="install-element-7" required="" class="form-control input-md col-md-6" name="c_password">
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" required="" placeholder="" id="subdomain" name="subdomain" class="form-control input-md col-md-6">
            <div class="form-actions col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 text-right">
                <input type="submit" id="install-element-9" class="btn btn-primary" name=""value="Valider">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to check by the functions `return` and not by `validate` ?

Comment: Where is `valid()` defined?

Comment: Can you show your HTML form?

Comment: i think you are using `jQuery Validation Plugin`. so You need to call `.validate()` also for validation. check here http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Comment: Try changing all your `input[name=xxx]` to be `input[name="xxx"]` (so with double quotes around the name.

Comment: Did you look for errors in the console (e.g. with Firebug)? It can be an error inside the conditional.

Comment: Solved! Found the error, subdomain_check() doesn't return true or false!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
$('#install').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    [..]
}
```

to your code

Comment: `return false` works fine. And also, if you would add your code, the form with OPs current code will not submit at all.